# Did the DCAU ever hint about Harley Quinn's bisexuality?

Tags: character, dc-animated-universe

Harley Quinn was first created for the [DC animated universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_animated_universe) (DCAU) and then made her way into comics and become quite famous. In the comics, she has shown various love interests (Joker, Batman, Deadshot, Poison Ivy etc.) which makes her bisexual (or maybe pansexual/omnisexual).

But did the DCAU ever show or hint about Harley Quinn's bisexuality?

Comment: Not yet I think, still doesn't happen to met with another female character that she had affairs in comics, may be in future they will

Comment: @VishwaMadushan DCAU ended long ago and there is no future for DCAU now

Comment: Is she confirmed to be bisexual; or does she simply have a flirtatious nature? The latter does not inherently prove the former. She stills seems to act flirtatiously towards characters that she doesn't like, e.g. Batman; so this would support the idea that her flirtatious behavior does not inherently reveal a love interest.

Comment: sorry I meant DCEU

Comment: @Flater [Harley is bissexual](https://moviepilot.com/posts/3910496). But I think Harley, such as Poison Ivy, have very distinct reasons for such. Neither of them (at least poison ivy) thinks as regular human beings. Harley is just crazy, and I think she just does whatever she wants. Poison Ivy in the other hand do not care for human beings as she cares for plants. Of course everything I just said is just their moral bases, which may as may not be overwritten by other factors in their character progressions.

Comment: @LeonFreire: Thanks for the link and confirmation. But although Harley is crazy, Harleen has modeled "Harley" on the Joker. And the Joker is a master manipulator. So it stands to reason that Harley would be flirtatious, as it is her biggest asset (as a pretty woman) to manipulate her (predominantly male) surroundings. Poison Ivy (and Catwoman, for that matter) seem to be flirtatious because their former selves were anything but flirtatious; both of these characters have been "liberated" from their past selves and now revel in their new found freedom to do what they have always wanted to do.

Comment: @Flater Yes, they are both flirtatious. The only thing I'm saying is that they are flirtatious with men and women. Harley and Ivy are a thing. What I meant with the previous comment is that they both probably have strong reasons to have an open mind on their sexuality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's been hinted a few times in [Batman: The Animated Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_The_Animated_Series) and its sequel [The New Batman Adventures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_Batman_Adventures). As far as I can remember, it's been hinted twice:

#### Batman: The Animated Series Episode 56: Harley and Ivy:

> When the Joker fires Harley, she tries going on a crime spree of her own, joining up with Poison Ivy, and the two become Gotham's Queens of Crime, much to the Joker's fury.

Harley spends the night at Ivy's, and in the morning there is a scene of the two preparing breakfast. Notice the clothing:

#### The New Batman Adventures Episode 1: Holiday Knights:

> Poison Ivy and Harley Quinn kidnap Bruce Wayne and use his credit cards for a shopping spree.

Prior to kidnapping Bruce, there's a scene of the two in their hotel room. Notice the clothing and that there's only one bed:

I think (as I haven't seen all the DCAU) that that's the closest they got at hinting it. Keep in mind that it's the DC**A**U.